# How does total depth affect the colloid gradient?

Tags: colloids

When a colloid reaches diffusion–sedimentation equilibrium, it creates a gradient where the solute concentrates toward the surface or the bottom of the vessel based on its density relative to the solvent even though it never completely separates.

This got me wondering, if you were to compare two vessels of different heights containing the same colloid solution, would the taller vessel have the same gradient slope, resulting in a greater difference between the concentration at top and bottom of the vessel, or would the slope become more shallow resulting in the same difference in concentrations, or would it be something in between?